# Loading the contents of the /opt/etc/profile file after reboot

Tags: busybox, openwrt, nas

I have a ZyXEL NAS326 network drive that runs BusyBox v1.19.4 with an additional OpenWrt repository. After each restart, the system does not see the path to the OpenWrt binary and does not remember the command history. Even though I run the command `. /opt/etc/profile` then after restart there is no command history and there is no path to the OpenWrt binary.
The default console on this NAS is ash.
How to configure the system so that the system always has an active command history in the console and has access to the OpenWrt bianrium in the path?

Comment: hm, can ash save the command history on a persistent piece of storage, i.e., is the ~ (home) directory of the user you're logging in as on something that survives a reboot?

Comment: and a script in /opt/etc/profile will not get automatically read; you'll need to modify /etc/profile

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your answer. I have modified the /etc/profile file and after reboot it still does not load the settings from this file. 
The OpenWrt binaries are located in /opt/bin/ and I enter this in the path section of the /etc/profile file. After reboot, the entry disappears from the file.

Comment: so, the file system on which /etc/ resides is not persistent, good to know! Does the same happen to your home directory? Can you create any file in your home directory, and see whether it's still there after a reboot?

Comment: I created the /home/test.txt file with the `touch /home/test.txt` command, entered the content 12345 into it. After rebooting, the file disappeared

Comment: The question is: where does the /etc/profile file template come from?
Originally, there was an entry `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${BASE_PATH}/sbin:/usr/local/zy-pkgs/bin:${BASE_PATH}/htp` in the PATH section, and after modification it looks like this: `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${BASE_PATH}/sbin:/usr/local/zy-pkgs/bin:${BASE_PATH}/htp:/opt/bin` and after reboot everything returns to its original state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, whether or not you busybox/ash saves history is a compile-time option¹; in other words, if there's no `.ash_history` file in your home directory after you ran at least one command, then there's nothing you can do – you need to use a different shell, which actually has that functionality. I'd say this might be wise in your use case anyways, because: "I want command history" just says "I use this shell more than one time to fix something", and that means that `ash` is really not the optimal interactive shell. It's meant to be slim, not to be a fully-fledged replacement for your desktop's shell!

Then:

> I created the /home/test.txt file with the `touch /home/test.txt` command, entered the content 12345 into it. After rebooting, the file disappeared

Seeing that your home directory is not persistent, there's no place to actually store the shell history! (it would normally be stored in `~/.ash_history`, but as you noticed, that doesn't get written to permanent storage, but probably remains on an in-RAM overlay that can't survive a reboot.)

Luckily in most shells, you can use the `HISTFILE` environment to set a different location. Busybox doesn't document that, but at least in its current code version, it does respect the variable. But which version with which options runs on your NAS – nobody knows! (Another indication that you, on such a system, probably want to run a less slimmed down shell, like, say, zsh).

> How to configure the system so that the system always has an active command history in the console and has access to the OpenWrt bianrium in the path?

You can't even write persistently to /etc, so I'll go with: You can't, until you figure out how to do that, which probably intentionally is not something that you can do. (It makes a consumer appliance much less unreliable, and much harder to persistently get unauthorized access after exposure of a security vulnerability, if you always know the root file system to be in the same factory state after a reboot. Clearly, a NAS is not *supposed* to be a terminal server!)

I don't know how this openwrt repository thing works, but I bet it comes with its own documentation – and quite possibly, software installed that way will look into /opt/etc instead of /etc, so if you can change your user's shell (using `chsh`) to something installed through openwrt in /opt/bin, maybe you can at least configure that.

Barring that, all you can do is hoping the SSH server (or whatever you use to log in) allows you to specify both environment variables (like `HISTFILE`, which you point to a location that your user can access, and which is persistent across reboots) and the command you want to run - then you could do something like

```bash
env 'HISTFILE=/path/to/persistent/storage/on/NAS/.zsh_history' \
    ssh \
      -o SendEnv=HISTFILE \
      -t \
      youruser@NAS_hostname_or_IP_address \
      /path/to/openwrt-installed/zsh/on/NAS/zsh
```

on your machine to make sure 1. that your openwrt-installed "proper" shell `zsh` is used, which does definitely save history, and 2. that it uses a persistent path to store its history.

---

> The question is: where does the /etc/profile file template come from? Originally, there was an entry `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${BASE_PATH}/sbin:/usr/local/zy-pkgs/bin:${BASE_PATH}/htp` in the PATH section, and after modification it looks like this: `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${BASE_PATH}/sbin:/usr/local/zy-pkgs/bin:${BASE_PATH}/htp:/opt/bin` and after reboot everything returns to its original state

You'd need to check how Zyxel builds their operating system images. Chances are you *could* do the same, with the desired modifications!

This [Marvell Presentation](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Arm%20Developer%20Community/PDF/ARMADA_Embedded_Processors_ext_for_ARM_July_2017_v5.pdf?la=en&revision=17f9100e-4ad7-44f2-a752-e7478e7fb498) (Marvell is the company that builds the SoC, the central processor, that your NAS is based on, says they ship a complete OpenEmbdedded/Yocto tree which allows integrators (such as Zyxel) to build Linux distributions fitting their exact use case. It's not unlikely Zyxel used that, modified the necessary layers, added their own software and uses it to build images. Now, Zyxel being a large vendor of mass-market network appliances, for whom security incidents become very costly, will probably (and for the aforementioned very good reason) have locked down their SecureBoot to only allow booting of signed firmware. That might simply not be something you can work around – there's proper cryptography that allows the hardware to tell a modified from an unmodified system image.

So, while you'd build such an image that contains modified /etc, there's the very realistic chance that you couldn't boot it, because you can't sign it. It all boils down to how much Zyxel locked down their system.

---

Frankly, um, I am *not* sure the root system on a small NAS appliance is what I'd want to have shell history on? That sounds like you'd want to figure out whether and how the app store of the vendor allows you to install a container or similarly isolated environment which allows you to run interactive shells more like you'd want to on a fully fledged desktop. But. Frankly. It's a 1.3 GHz single-core ARMv7 with only 512 MB RAM (which is extremely little for a storage appliance). I do hope Zyxel put a lot of work into optimizing storage accesses through network with DMA, because otherwise it'd be already heavily tasked with just juggling benign network speeds while accessing files, and I'm not convinced this is a platform you'd want to run *anything* else on.

---

¹ For the future embedded dev reader, compiling their own busybox: The compile-time option is `ENABLE_FEATURE_EDITING_SAVEHISTORY`.